# System.Text.StringBuilder limit

Tags: c#, .net, performance, string

I've read that the StringBuilder type has a limit (the default is 16 characters), and when you append some text to it, beyond its limit, a new instance is created with a higher limit and the data is copied to it. I tried that using the following code :

```
StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP",16);
test.Append("ABC");
```

And the CIL generated for that was :

```
  .maxstack  3
  .locals init (class [mscorlib]System.Text.StringBuilder V_0)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldstr      "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP"
  IL_0006:  ldc.i4.s   16
  IL_0008:  newobj     instance void [mscorlib]System.Text.StringBuilder::.ctor(string, int32)
  IL_000d:  stloc.0
  IL_000e:  ldloc.0
  IL_000f:  ldstr      "ABC"
  IL_0014:  callvirt   instance class [mscorlib]System.Text.StringBuilder [mscorlib]System.Text.StringBuilder::Append(string)
  IL_0019:  pop
  IL_001a:  ret
```

Setting the limit to, say, 32 :

```
StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP",32);
test.Append("ABC");
```

Generated exactly the same IL code.
What I expect is creating a new instance in the first case, and changing the value of the instance in the second case, which obviously didn't happen, any clue why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All the fun stuff happens in this line:

```
IL_0014:  callvirt   instance class [mscorlib]System.Text.StringBuilder [mscorlib]System.Text.StringBuilder::Append(string)
```

This is where you make the call to the `Append()` method, but the IL you have posted does not contain the body of that method. Look in the [source code](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/10/03/releasing-the-source-code-for-the-net-framework-libraries.aspx) for the StringBuilder class (it's released under a license that allows you to have a look), and see what happens within the `Append()` method.

**Spoiler alert!** A look at the source code of `Append()` will reveal that the internal buffer is indeed increased whenever the length of the concatenated string exeeds the current size of the buffer.

Comment: But the resulting CIL code shows that it's not, as I understand the CIL code a new string builder is created whenever I append text to it, just like a new string is created when you manipulate a string.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - where in the IL are you looking? I see only one call to the constructor (IL_0008), and one to the Append() method (IL_0008). This seems to reflect your C# code very well.

Comment: NO, a new stringbuilder object is NOT created.  The existing stringbuilder allocates a new BUFFER.

Comment: You don't get a new instance of your StringBuilder. The reallocation happens inside the StringBuilder and doesn't affect the calling code.

Comment: In my understanding the OP's point was that the StringBuilder was created with the same buffer, regardless of whether he used 32 or 16 as that parameter.

Comment: In case hangy's interpretation of the is correct: have a look at the source code of the constrcutor(s) of StringBuilder. It does indeed use the provided length, when making a call to the internal string.GetStringForStringBuilder() method.

Answer (score 3):

This C# code

```
using System.Text;

internal class Program
{
    internal static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP", 16);
        test.Append("ABC");

        StringBuilder test2 = new StringBuilder("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP", 32);
        test2.Append("ABC");
    }
}
```

produces the following IL (according to Reflector):

```
.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit Program
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor() cil managed
    {
        .maxstack 8
        L_0000: ldarg.0 
        L_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        L_0006: ret 
    }

    .method assembly hidebysig static void Main(string[] args) cil managed
    {
        .entrypoint
        .maxstack 3
        .locals init (
            [0] class [mscorlib]System.Text.StringBuilder test,
            [1] class [mscorlib]System.Text.StringBuilder test2)
        L_0000: nop 
        L_0001: ldstr "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP"
        L_0006: ldc.i4.s 0x10
        L_0008: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Text.StringBuilder::.ctor(string, int32)
        L_000d: stloc.0 
        L_000e: ldloc.0 
        L_000f: ldstr "ABC"
        L_0014: callvirt instance class [mscorlib]System.Text.StringBuilder [mscorlib]System.Text.StringBuilder::Append(string)
        L_0019: pop 
        L_001a: ldstr "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP"
        L_001f: ldc.i4.s 0x20
        L_0021: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Text.StringBuilder::.ctor(string, int32)
        L_0026: stloc.1 
        L_0027: ldloc.1 
        L_0028: ldstr "ABC"
        L_002d: callvirt instance class [mscorlib]System.Text.StringBuilder [mscorlib]System.Text.StringBuilder::Append(string)
        L_0032: pop 
        L_0033: ret 
    }
}
```

So here, `0x10` and `0x20` are used to initalize `test` and `test2`, which means you probably looked at the wrong IL in your test?

Comment: Thanks! What does "ldc.i4.s 0x10/0x20" means?

Comment: 0x20 (hex) = 32 dez, 0x10 (hex) = 16 dez :)
I am not really familiar with IL, but I'd assume that's the constructor parameter set in HEX values.

Answer (score 2):

A StringBuilder has a Capacity property, like most Collection classes. When the collection grows beyond the Capacity, the internal data-structure (not the object itself) is re-allocated, and I think most (I am sure about StringBuilder and List< >) use the doubling strategy. And yes, that involves creating a new array and copying of the old data.

If you have any information about how big the endresult is going to be, use something like:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(n); // set initial Capacity=n
```

It is not a bad idea to take a high estimate, and maybe add some extra space. Better to allocate a few chars too many then to have it copied midway.

This is the price we pay to have collections (StringBuilder is like a collection of char) that can grow automatically. I guess that alternatives, like a linked list of blocks, were deemed to complex.

Comment: Please clarify more how "the internal data-structure (not the object itself) is re-allocated", thank you.

Comment: StringBuilder needs some internal storage to hold the text, I'm guessing it's something like char[] text = new char[Capacity]

If it recreated the actual StringBuilder it wouldn't be able to update all references to the object, something that would wreak havoc.

Comment: Think of a class with a class-level variable holding an array. Can you replace the array stored in this variable with a different array instance without changing the instance of the class? Of course you can!

Comment: Joel, your example was great to understand the issue, thanks a million :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you misread the IL code. The following line:

```
 IL_0014:  callvirt   instance class [mscorlib]System.Text.StringBuilder [mscorlib]System.Text.StringBuilder::Append(string)
```

...does not mean that a new StringBuilder instance is created; it is merely a call to the `Append` method.

If calling `Append` would result in a string that is longer than the current capacity of the `StringBuilder`, it will create a new `String` instance *internally*; it will still be the same `StringBuilder` instance.

Comment: I'm very curious about how a new string instance is created internally, in fact, this is what I'm trying to understand, thanks!